# ¿Cómo puedo configurar varios hosts virtuales para que se acceda a ellos desde un mismo DNS?

Tags: apache, dns, ubuntu-server

ahora mismo estoy desarrollando 2 páginas web distintas (asociadas a dominios distintos) y cuento con un servidor web montado sobre apache2 para subirlas. Por el momento tengo las rutas donde se alojan las páginas web (/var/www/dominio1 y /var/www/dominio2) y un host virtual por cada dominio, habilitados en /etc/apache2/sites-enabled y con el siguiente contenido:

Host virtual 1:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@dominio1
    ServerName dominio1
    ServerAlias www.dominio1
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dominio1
    ErrorLog $(APACHE_LOG_DIR)/error.log
    CustomLog $(APACHE_LOG_DIR)/error.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Host virtual 2:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@dominio2
    ServerName dominio2
    ServerAlias www.dominio2
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dominio2
    ErrorLog $(APACHE_LOG_DIR)/error.log
    CustomLog $(APACHE_LOG_DIR)/error.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

La intención con estos 2 dominios es que funcionen bajo demanda por nombre de dominio, pero entiendo que tendré que configurar un DNS global para ello, ¿podría asociar un mismo servidor DNS a 2 dominios distintos de alguna forma? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Sí se puede asociar múltiples dominios a un mismo servidor. Cómo tienes configurado el DNS actualmente? O no lo has hecho aún?

Comment: Por el momento no prácticamente nada del DNS, solo tengo instalado el paquete bind9.

Comment: El primer paso es "delegar" el DNS de los dominios a tu servidor. Eso se hace en el sitio donde compraste los dominios. Eso ya lo hiciste?

Comment: Creo que si. Lo compré en don dominio, y en el apartado de zona DNS tengo un registro de tipo A apuntando a la IP pública de mi router para ambos dominios

Comment: Por si vale de algo, se me pasó comentarlo antes, estoy haciendo el servidor sobre Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Entonces ya está todo listo. Qué problema estás teniendo específicamente?

Answer (score 0):

Los DNS con tu proveedor los has de dirijir a tu ip. y apache a travez de tus directivas especificadas httpd-vhosts.conf  hacen el resto. No hay más.

```
#<VirtualHost *:80>  
    #ServerAdmin ejemplo@icloud.com
    #DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/wordpress"
    #ServerName name"ó ip" 95.20.221.117 
    #ServerAlias  www.95.20.221.117
    #ErrorLog "logs/ejemplo.dns2go.info-error.log"
    #CustomLog "logs/ejemplo.dns2go.info-access.log" common
#</VirtualHost>
```

Bueno sí. Abre los puertos en el router, Abre los puertos o quita el cortafuegos de tu sistema operativo